# Datastorage class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I just need a basic explanation.
I'm going to create some sample code maybe someone can help me with- been working on this for hours but I just don't understand how to use classes properly with things like arrays. I've already read the javadocs stuff but i'm still confused. If someone can show me how to solve this I'd greatly appreciate it since it means I can apply to the problem I'm trying to solve which is much larger.

```
public class main{
    int id =0;
    double data1 = 0;
    double data2 = 0;
    double data3 = 0;    

    public static void main(String[] args){
            id++;  // do some stuff to the data. 
    }

    public class datastorage{ 

    /*I want to create an array of arrays in this class to store the
    hanging values from the main class 
    e.g. {{1,34.2,34.6,23.1}{2,38.2,33.6,22.6}}
    I then want to be able to call each array back to the main to display depending on
     which ID I choose. */
    }
```

Comment: May be it is time to spend sometime on reading basics?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Comment: the formatting messed up when I pasted it sadly =[

Comment: It is not just the formatting though. For instance class names should start with a capital letter. When you class name is two words each word should start with a capital letter (`datastorage` should be `DataStorage`. Variables should be declared as public, protected or private, generally the accepted standards are private with public or protected getters and setters where appropriate. That is why the tutorial linked would be beneficial for you to read through.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I appreciate it however that's just a quick model I typed up to demo my problem.

Comment: Here is the problem though, when you are asking for help, the things listed serve as a distraction to those trying to help. They see these things, and it is hard for them to move past them. Most people here want to help, and will be inclined to spend more effort to point out these basic items to you, then to answer your actual questions. As most believe you need to learn to crawl before you walk. Just something to keep in mind when asking for help.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just define a separate class to hold this data - and then maintain a list of instances of this class?

For example,

```
public class MyClass { 
    int id =0; 
    double data1 = 0; 
    double data2 = 0;
    double data3 = 0;

    ...
}
```

Then in your main method you could perhaps use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
...
```

---

If this is not possible for whatever reason, you can still opt to create an array of `double[]`s to hold the data (like you mentioned).

```
double[][] data = new double[4][MAX_ENTERIES];
data[0] = new double[]{1,34.2,34.6,23.1};
data[1] = new double[]{2,38.2,33.6,22.6};
...
```

To find a specific id in `data`, you can simply loop through its arrays:

```
for (double[] arr : data)
    if (arr[0] == someId)
        // do something
```

Comment: It's not really doable- I'm almost done and don't really want to change that part of my code really. All I want to do is store the data in an array of arrays in a second class then I can then recall ideally? =S

Comment: Sorry but can you put it inside the sample code- so I can see how the two classes interact with one another please?

Answer (score -1):

Start by taking the [Java coding standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) to heart.

Your naming convention is confusing.  Class name "main"?  You can do better.

The code you've posted is quite confusing.  I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Apologies, I've just cleaned it up a bit. And that's just a basic bare bones of the actual application I quickly just typed to demo my problem.

Comment: This code doesn't deserve the name of bare bones.  Voting to close, sorry.

Comment: @duffymo While I agree with your sentiment, this isn't really an answer and is a comment. Also if you had listed out at least a few of items and what they should have been it would have been a learning opportunity for some instead of what really just came off as condescending.

Comment: jschoen, I'd advise you to stop commenting and start answering.  If you think it's worth your time to do better, please go right ahead.  You've offered nothing that I can see.  The recommendation of the Java coding standards is certainly worth more than the nothing you've offered.